# How give a recommendation letter to my professor when I need it back?

Tags: recommendation-letter

Basically, i have asked a professor if he would write a recommendation letter for me and he graciously agreed.

But for some reason, this recommendation letter needs to come back to me because it has to be in my complete application I need to send in the end. (The complete application is a hard copy that needs to be mailed)

Do I mail the professor a hard copy of the recommendation letter with a stamp so he can send it back after he fills it out? If I do this, do i ask him for his address? (its summer now)

Or do I send him an email with the soft copy of the form attached and ask him to print it out and mail it to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask him what he would prefer?

Comment: Either ways would do. I would recommend having him send it, not you, as this letter is meant to provide his feedback about you.  However, you may provide him the stamp to facilitate the process.

Answer (score 2):

She or he could write your recommendation letter, and put it in a sealed envelope. Then, you submit your application with the sealed envelope.

Comment: Most applications required copies of the documents - not the originals... I spent many hours photocopying cerificates, reference letters etc...